# How to insert data using mysql encode function in codeigniter

Tags: php, mysql, codeigniter-3

I am using Codeigniter and I want to encode my string using `encode()` function in Mysql. Is there a way to use that function using `$this->db->insert($table_name, $data);` in Codeigniter? Here is my sample codes:

CI controller:

```
$data_array('id' => 1, 'name' => 'Juan Dela Cruz');
$this->load->model('data_mdl');
$this->data_mdl->_insert($data_array);
```

CI model:

```
public function _insert($data) {
 return $this->db->insert($table_name, $data);
}
```

Any help would be appreciated. Thanks.

Comment: Can you show the code where you tried using `encode()` and it did not work?

Comment: Hi, I don't know how to use that in `$this->db->insert($table_name, $data);` but i know how to use this using Mysql query like `INSERT INTO MyGuests (name)
VALUES (ENCODE('Juan Dela Cruz', 'mysecretkey')";`

Comment: I can use `$this->db->query("INSERT INTO MyGuests (name) VALUES (ENCODE('Juan Dela Cruz', 'mysecretkey')");` to execute Mysql query, but I wonder if there is a way in `$this->db->insert($table_name, $data);` CI function that will also produce the same output. thanks

Comment: Try Enoch's answer and let us  know if there are any problems.

Answer (score 0):

Why don't you simple encode your data then send it.

```
$this->db->insert($table_name, encode($data));
```

or

```
$data = array();
$data = encode($data);

$this->db->insert($table_name, $data);
```

or

```
$data = array();
$data = 'ENCODE('. $data .')'; 
$this->db->insert($table_name, $data);
```

EDITED  FROM HERE: 
The MYSQL function Encode() just as the name suggests encodes the data, you then unencode that data using the reverse function.

My suggestion would be to use something simple as base64_encode which works with the same principle with a reverse function, base64_decode.

In that case you would use this following code: **SOLUTION 1**

CI controller:

```
// ENCODING
$data_array = array('id' => 1, 'name' => 'Juan Dela Cruz');
$serialized = serialize($data_array); 
$encoded = base64_encode($serialized);

$this->load->model('data_mdl');
$this->data_mdl->_insert($encoded);


// DECODING     
$encoded = //DO QUERY HERE TO GET ENCODED DATA;
$decoded = base64_decode($encoded);
$unserialized = unserialize($decoded);
```

CI model:

```
public function _insert($data) {
 return $this->db->insert($table_name, $data);
}
```

You can also use CI inbuilt encrypt library: **SOLUTION 2**
More details can be found here: https://www.formget.com/codeigniter-encrypt/

Comment: Please see the edited question above. I put some codes that I used.

Comment: will give you a full PHP solution shortly, typing up

Comment: will give you a full PHP solution shortly, typing up

Answer (score 0):

I solve my problem by using `$this->db->set()` function in my CI model.

```
public function _insert($data) {
 $this->db->set('name', 'ENCODE(\'' . $data['name'] . '\', \'mysecretkey\')', false);
 unset($data['name']);
 return $this->db->insert($table_name, $data);
}
```

I don't know if this is the right way but it solved my problem.